# What is wrong about Abs[x]-a? Is it a bug?

Tags: functions, programming, mathematical-optimization

[image]

Why is the `Out[74]` not `{1 - a, {x -> -1}}`?

```
 Maximize[{Sqrt[x^2] - a, -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

> ```
> {1 - a, {x -> -1}}
> ```

Comment: Please post germane code, not pictures...

Comment: Plot it. Think about it. Then try `Maximize[{(Abs[x] - a), -1 <= x <= 1}, {x, a}]` and see what you get. It is not a but.

Comment: @rasher I may be overlooking something obvious, but isn't the maximum always going to be `1 - a`? It's not clear to me why MMA would return a symbolic maximum in the other instances and not here.

Comment: I think it is a bug but it works it you assign an exact number to a

Comment: In[1]:= Maximize[{(Abs[x] - a), -1 <= x <= 1}, {x, a}]

Out[1]= {\[Infinity], {x -> Indeterminate, a -> Indeterminate}}

Comment: In[2]:= Maximize[{Abs[x] - a, -1 <= x <= 1}, x]

Out[2]= Maximize[{-a + Abs[x], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]

Comment: In[3]:= Maximize[{Abs[x] - a, -1 <= x <= 1}, x, Reals]

Out[3]= Maximize[{-a + Abs[x], -1 <= x <= 1}, x, Reals]

Comment: Everyone. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sometimes Mathematica cannot solve a problem.  I think only the programmers working on this function would be able to decide whether this is a bug (i.e. it doesn't give an answer because something goes wrong an an unintended way inside the function) or it's just something Mathematica can't do.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the reason this fails is because *Mathematica* does not know the derivative of `Abs[x]`. The reason behind this is `Abs[x]` is nowhere differentiable in the complex plane and `Derivative` and `D` take complex derivatives.

In Wolfram Alpha, we had to handle `Abs` ourselves assuming real variables since most people would want that. If you run `WolframAlpha["derivative of Abs[x]"]`, you'll see the step-by-step solution specifies x is a real variable.

Since `Derivative` is not a protected symbol, we can add custom `SubValues`:

```
Derivative[1][Abs] = Sign;
Derivative[2][Abs] = Derivative[1][Sign] = DiracDelta;
```

Now *Mathematica* knows the (real) derivatives of these functions:

```
D[Abs[x], x]
(* Sign[x] *)

D[Abs[x], {x, 2}]
(* DiracDelta[x] *)

D[Sign[x], x]
(* DiracDelta[x] *)
```

Unfortunately this does not fix your `Maximize` issue:

```
Maximize[{Abs[x] - a, -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
(* Maximize[{-a + Abs[x], -1 <= x <= 1}, x] *)
```